# Spark Decision Tree with LIBSVM data error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, libsvm, apache-spark-mllib

I converted a CSV to LIBSVM data format using Python. The format of the LIBSVM is like below. The first column is the target.

```
    0 0:1 1:2 2:1 4:11 6:4 7:7 8:1 9:99 10:70 11:1
    0 0:1 1:2 2:1 4:8 5:1 6:3 7:7 8:1 9:99 10:62 11:1
```

My code in MLLib Decision Tree in Spark is

```
    from pyspark.mllib.tree import DecisionTree, DecisionTreeModel
    from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    sc = SparkContext()

    data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc,"/folder/libdata.txt")
    (trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

    model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData)
    print(model.toDebugString())

    model.save(sc, "/folder/myDecisionTreeClassificationModel")
```

The error I am getting is

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: You provided 12 indices and values, which exceeds the specified vector size 11
```

Don't know where it is going wrong. The Format of data also is correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What likely happens here is that the zero-based feature indices throw MLLib off when determining the number of features in your data set. Try shifting all feature indices in your input data up by 1, starting at 1 and ending at 12 (e.g. `0 1:1 2:2 3:1 5:11 7:4 8:7 9:1 10:99 11:70 12:1` for your first example line).

If you collect and print `data`, you can see how index 0 (libsvm) became index -1 (in Spark) and how the largest index is 10 (corresponding to 11 in the libsvm files). The code calculating the number of features (see https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/aedbbaa3dda9cbc154cd52c07f6d296b972b0eb2/python/pyspark/mllib/util.py#L120) takes the highest index and adds one, i.e. 11, but you have 12 features.

Alternatively, you can try passing the right number of features into the `loadLibSVMFile` call (via `numFeatures`), but the -1 index may still throw things off.